# How to get element with same data-attr on all site with only css?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, less

There is a task - to randomly find an element with a date-attribute on a site with a large nesting. This task I should do only with CSS, without JS (maybe some compile from SASS or LESS). Someone has an idea how to find any block with [data-some="true"]? Can you help me? please?

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="row-1">
       <div class="child-first></div>
       <div class="child-second>
           <div data-some="true"></div>
           <div data-some="true"></div>
           <div data-some="true"></div>
       </div>
    <div>
    <div class="row-2">
       <div class="child-first></div>
       <div class="child-second>
           <div data-some="true"></div>
           <div data-some="true"></div>
           <div data-some="true"></div>
       </div>
    <div>
    ...
    <div class="row-n">
       <div class="child-first></div>
       <div class="child-second>
           <div data-some="true"></div>
           <div data-some="true"></div>
           <div data-some="true"></div>
       </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You was very close and can use `[data-some="true"]` directly as CSS selector:

```css
[data-some="true"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="not_nested">
    <div data-some="false">test</div>
    <div data-some="true">test</div>
    <div data-some="true">test</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="row-2">
      <div class="nested">
        <div data-some="true">test</div>
        <div data-some="false">test</div>
        <div data-some="true">test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-n">
      <div class="child-first"></div>
      <div class="child-second">
        <div class="deeper_nested">
          <div data-some="true">test</div>
          <div data-some="true">test</div>
          <div data-some="false">test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I only need to take one element with [data-some="true"]. Without knowing anything about the nesting depth, the number of elements with [data-some="true"] and the class names of the parents of these elements

Comment: You can add `:first-child` or `:nth-child()` but you can't get one randomly without JavaScript. Even with SASS or LESS it isn't possible...

Comment: I was hoping that there were new opportunities in css. But still thank you very much

Comment: What about :nth-child() - this will prevent me from accessing the elements in <div class = "row-2">.
If I call [data-some="true"]:nth-child(3) for your example - it will gives me 'null'.

Comment: You could also use `last-child()` or `nth-of-type()` or you could combine multiple of these selectors to get a nested element. But for all that you have to know the HTML structure, like your last comment shows. And you can forget about a random selection in CSS. Even in SASS or LESS the random function works only while compiling the CSS for the browser. The compiled CSS is static again...